# JSF, PrimeFaces, or RichFaces etc. components requiring h:form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces

How do you know which JSF, PrimeFaces, RichFaces etc. components actually **require** an h:form around them?

Does `<h:link>` generally require a form?

Does `<p:dataTable>` generally require a form?

Does `<p:dataGrid>` generally require a form?

...

How do you know **without** having to trial and error through "The button/link/text component needs to have a Form in its ancestry. Please add `<h:form>`." faces messages?

Answer (score 3):

Any component that you want to send data to the server needs a form around it. I.e. every inputBox, textArea, checkbox etc. If you only want to retrieve data from the server but not send anything back you don't need a form.

So `<dataTable>` doesn't generally require a form, but if you want to make it editable then you'd need a form.

Comment: `<h:link>` doesn't require a `<h:form>` either.